# How to create a Haar Cascade which recognizes only me?

Tags: opencv, object-detection, opencv3.0, face-detection, haar-classifier

I'm trying to make my first Haar Cascade and I'm thinking of making one which recognizes **only my face**. How do i do this? I'm assuming that i'll need to use my face in the positive images but then shouldn't negative images include **other faces** so that it's able to differentiate between them and I?

I'd really appreciate if someone could some up with an explanation of this.
Thanks.

Comment: i dont think cascadeClassifier is suitable for that problem, but if you want to try, then yes: positives have to be your faces (many sanples) and negatives should be anything, including a lot of other people's faces.

Answer (score 0):

SentDex has a great tutorial on Haar Cascade.
Check his official website: 
https://pythonprogramming.net/haar-cascade-object-detection-python-opencv-tutorial/

Or just go to youtube and search for "SentDex Haar Cascade".